# Problem with reindex catalog_product_prices

Tags: error, indexer

Having a problem with reindexing catalog_product_prices. I get the following error message:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tad_price_type.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_pric' at line 14' in /home/vampow/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND tad_price_type.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tas_pric' at line 14' in /home/vampow/public_html/store/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234

This is the SQL line that is causing the problem (14):

> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `tad_price_type` ON tad_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price_type.attribute_id =  AND tad_price_type.store_id = 0

Ran Database repair tool. Result was database didn't require any changes.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your error your query doesn't look correct: **tad_price_type.attribute_id**

```
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS tad_price_type ON tad_price_type.entity_id = e.entity_id AND tad_price_type.attribute_id = AND tad_price_type.store_id = 0
```

The table catalog_product_entity doesn't have any **attribute_id** column.

Most of the times this happens after a new module is installed. You should try:

1. Check that all the new module files have the right ownership and
   permissions.
2. Flush all caches.
3. Try reindexing from command line:
   `php shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Good luck!